# How to see sqlalchemy database?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask webapp that uses flask-sqlalchemy as a database.I am new to this so i dont know how can i see or delete columns in database.I know it exists but i cant see data in it.How can i access data i put into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy is not a database. It is an ORM for a database (Flask-SQLAlchemy is a pythonic way to represent any supported database).

If you are using Postgres as DB then you can use [PGAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) as DB explorer. Similarly, if you are using SQLite DB you can download [SQLite DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Comment: I am using postgres but how exacly can i see it.Do I need to import it or something?

Comment: Install the software pgadmin (I've added link in answer). Consider these softwares as  GUI for your database.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the database using the "User.query.all()" to check/see all data or can use filter_by to get the specific data based on your requirements.
Check the https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/ to understand it thoroughly.